# Dynamic Tree Generation in Flex Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4.5

I am using the [URL](http://www.programmingwall.com/flex/creating-a-dynamic-tree-in-flex/) logic for creating a dynamic Tree in Flex using action script. However the `output is not properly shown (Object name is shown instead of Label).` [image]

Code is available in above mentioned URL.

Please help.

Comment: post code post code post code

Comment: It is better that you read the question properly

Comment: It is better that you properly post code so we can show you exactly where you went wrong. Or do you prefer everyone to keep on guessing like Max did down below. Did it ever occur to you that most Flex developers have had and seen this before. It's an easy fix but to fix it we need to see how the data provider is set up and see the mxml where you are generating the object. Are you that ashamed of your code that you can't show it to people?

Comment: @The_asMan comments are reserved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a correct toString() implementation of your DataTreeNode, so it would have a proper display in this tree.

An example: Provided the class DataTreeNode has a data:Object field, and this object has a urlToDisplay:String property that you want displayed. Do like this:

```
override public function toString():String {
    if (!data) return '[null]';
    return data.urlToDisplay;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only rely on simple Objects or data classes, you can use the tree's **labelField** or **labelFunction** in order to read and/or format data, which is passed to the renderer. There are no new item renderer classes needed.

New renderer should be compatible with these functions!

On a site note: item renderer are not "mostly just simple MXML classes", they are component instances. It doesn't matter how there are implemented. There are best practises like avoiding data bindings in item renderers, that's why it is common to use the markup for drawing, but implementing the views behaviour according to the Flex component live cycle. you might want to read about it in the documentation, because it is a necessary read for a Flex developer.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to write an ItemRenderer that tells your tree how it should display the components. ItemRenderers are mostly just simple MXML classes that access one item each and display the data in any way you want. You will have to assign the ItemRenderer to your component.

See this article:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html

Comment: He doesn't need a renderer to target the data object label.

Comment: Implementing an ItemRenderer that reads the data object's label and displays it would be one way of doing this. If the data object doesn't only contain the label's text but also the label object itself, then he should consider separating these elements. Data objects usually don't contain display objects.